# How to give some color for province or some city in google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I need to cover some city by using some color, in some area. I am using google maps API, can give me some idea how to solve this?

Example:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But I agree here: just dropping "I need X", rarely does work here. You are much better of trying yourself first. Then: asking for tutorials or libraries, tools, ... is all off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a polygon using the Polygon class.

Simple example from google provided.

The paths property can take an array of arrays to create multiple polygons.

See the full example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

And documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon

Eg:

```
var triangleCoords = [
    [ 
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
        {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
        {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
    ],
    [
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
        {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
        {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
    ]
];
```

Hope that helps.

```js
// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polygon</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bergstrom Thanks before it gives me some idea, but did u know how to make the shape looks like the city or province shape? thankyou

Comment: @EgaJavier If you can find a data source with latitude and longitudes for your Polygon you can format that data to the format provided in the example. If you can't find a data source you would have to create the data yourself. You could, for example, use this tool http://www.gmapgis.com/. And save the data as geoJSON, and load the data on to your map using this technique: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple